# Есть ли разница между "два часа" и "второй час"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли разница, когда говорим: "два часа" / "второй час"? 
Например: "Ждал автобус два часа" или "Ждал автобус второй час". Всегда ведь будет один и тот же результат? (Например, 10:00—12:00). Или "Второй час" — имеется в виду, что идёт второй час?

Comment: Если вы получили полезный ответ, отметьте его галочкой, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Разница есть.

**Два часа** - это два полных часа, 120 минут.
**Второй час** - это один час и ещё сколько-то минут от второго часа, что меньше 120 минут.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Два часа** — это **конкретный** период времени, равный 120 минутам.
   **Второй час** — это **растянутый** промежуток времени, от часа одной минуты (61 минуты) до обычно часа 30 минут (90 минут).

Когда время ожидания переваливает за 90 минут, мы чаще всего говорим *жду полтора часа*.
Еще дальше по длительности — жду более полутора часов; жду около двух часов; жду почти два часа; жду два часа (120 минут).

2. Глагол [**ждать**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) требует после себя существительное в родительном падеже, если речь идет о каком-то абстрактном автобусе (поезде, самолете), поэтому правильно говорить так: *жду автобуса два часа, жду автобуса второй час.*

Если же речь идет о конкретном маршруте, то используется винительный падеж:
*жду автобус Санкт-Петербург—Таллинн второй час.*